Windows Explorer and Files app both fail after Windows update - "Explorer.EXE Application not found"
I'm encountering a critical issue with my file explorer on Windows. Here are the details:



The problem:

When I try to run File Explorer, I get the error: "Explorer.EXE Application not found"
This happened after a recent Windows update today
Neither the default Windows File Explorer nor the Files app is working

What I've tried:

Running sfc /scannow (completed successfully but didn't resolve the issue)
Running DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth (completed but didn't fix the problem)
Attempting to re-register explorer.exe with regsvr32 /n /i explorer.exe, which returned an error




Additional context:

A couple of days before the Windows update, I set the Files app as my default file explorer from within the app's settings
The Explorer.exe file exists in C:\Windows\explorer.exe

Questions:

How can I further diagnose this issue?
What steps can I take to restore functionality to the default File Explorer?
Could setting Files as the default explorer have contributed to this problem, and if so, how can I revert this change?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I managed to solve this issue. The problem was caused by the Files app changing the default file explorer in the Windows Registry. Here's how I fixed it:

Open an elevated Command Prompt.

Run the following command to check the current file explorer setting:
reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open\command" /ve

This showed that Files app was set as the default:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open\command
    (Default)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Files\Files.App.Launcher.exe" "%1"


To revert to the default Windows File Explorer, I ran:
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open\command" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "explorer.exe %1" /f



After this, both the Windows File Explorer and the Files app started working correctly.
